# Why are two click events registered in this html/css/jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I am trying to style a checkbox list. I've added my styles and they appear correctly when rendered. I want to add a class when the label for the checkbox is clicked. This is my markup and [here is the same in a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fdm1pmj2/1/). You can see from my fiddle that two click events are registered with just one click. Why?

html:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label for="test_0" class="">
            <input id="test_0" name="offering_cycle" type="checkbox" value="1"> Fall
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="test_1" class="">
            <input id="test_1" name="offering_cycle" type="checkbox" value="2"> Spring
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="test_2" class="">
            <input id="test_2" name="offering_cycle" type="checkbox" value="3"> Summer
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="test_3" class="">
            <input id="test_3" name="offering_cycle" type="checkbox" value="4"> Other
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}
label {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:27px;
    height:25px;
}
label:before {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:-2px;
    margin-left:-28px;
    width:18px;
    height:18px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:18px;
    content:'a';
}
input {
    width:1px;
    height:1px;
    border:0;
    opacity:0;
    float:right;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('label[for*=test_]').on('click',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('testing');
});
```

Comment: You're binding a click event to the label but if someone clicks on an element inside the label it might create two click events.  One for the child element and one for the parent element.

Comment: @b_dubb exactly my thoughts. I am convinced it generates a click event for the input too!

Comment: You can take input out of the label. It seems controls will look the same and you won't have this issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Reason the label's click handler is called twice:**

Clicking on a label that is associated with an input causes two click events to be triggered. The first click event is triggered for the label. The default handling of that click event causes a second click event to get triggered for the associated input. Since you have the input as a descendant of the label, the second click event bubbles up to the label. That is why your click event handler is called twice.

---

**If you really want to handle a click event for the label (and have it execute only once for a click):**

(1) If you are willing and able to modify the HTML, you could move the input so it is not a descendant of the label. There will still be two click events, but the second click event will not bubble up from the input to the label since the label is no longer an ancestor of the input.

When the input is not a descendant of the label, you must use the label's "for" attribute to associated it with the input. The value of the "for" attribute should be the "id" value of the input. (You are already including the "for" attribute with the proper value.)

```
<input id="test_0" name="offering_cycle" type="checkbox" value="1">
<label for="test_0" class="">Fall</label>
```

---

(2) Preventing the default handling of the first click event prevents the second click event from getting triggered, ***BUT doing this breaks the label***. That is, the checkbox will not get checked/unchecked when the label is clicked.

```
$('label[for*=test_]').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('testing');
    // returning false would be another way to prevent the default handling.
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43rp5zbL/)

---

(3) Instead, you could stop the second click event from bubbling up from the input.

```
$('input:checkbox').on('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$('label[for*=test_]').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('testing');
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r1nwa5rs/)

Note: If the input was not a child of the label, this would not be necessary.

---

(4) Or you could check the event target in the handler. It will be the label for the first click event and the input for the second. The following handler executes the code inside the if-statement only for the first click event.

```
$('label[for*=test_]').on('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target == this) {
        $(this).toggleClass('testing');
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6s7Lfoa/1/)

Note: If the input was not a child of the label, the code above would still work, but the if-statement would be unnecessary because the click event triggered for the input would not bubble up to the label.

---

**Handling the click for the input instead:**

In your case, you don't really need to register a click handler for the label element. You could register a click (or change) handler for the input instead. You could then use `$(this).closest('label')` to get the label element.

```
$('input[name=offering_cycle]').on('click', function() {
     $(this).closest('label').toggleClass('testing');
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h98vyj0e/)

Note: If the input was not a child of the label, the handler above would still get called when you click on the label, but `$(this).closest('label')` would not get the label. You would have to use something like `$('label[for="' + this.id + '"]')` instead.

---

**Regarding the "for" attribute on the label elements:**

Since you have the inputs inside the labels, it is not necessary to include the `for` attributes on the labels --- but it's not invalid.

You have set the "for" attribute values to the values of the "id" attributes of the input elements. That is the correct way to use the "for" attribute to associated a label with an input. If you were to include a "for" attribute with an invalid value, the label would not be associated with the input, even if the input is a descendant of the label.

From the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-label-for) for the "for" attribute of a label element:

> The for attribute may be specified to indicate a form control with
>   which the caption is to be associated. If the attribute is specified,
>   the attribute's value must be the ID of a labelable element in the
>   same Document as the label element. If the attribute is specified and
>   there is an element in the Document whose ID is equal to the value of
>   the for attribute, and the first such element is a labelable element,
>   then that element is the label element's labeled control.
>
> If the for attribute is not specified, but the label element has a
>   labelable element descendant, then the first such descendant in tree
>   order is the label element's labeled control.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try:

```
$('label[for^="test_"]').click(function(){
    $('div#target').append($(this).clone());
    return false;    
});
```

Comment: Actually this should be used: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: We've figured out the issue is that the event propagates twice. Returning `false` stops this, and it is very concise which makes me like this answer a lot. I'm just curious if a more verbose answer would be better as looking back on this code later I may not understand why I did it this way. Using something like `stopPropagation()` seems more friendly.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Will `preventDefault()` stop the input from being checked?

Comment: @jefffabiny yes. It'll not be checked.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're binding event on `label` which contains `checkbox` and you're using `for="chekbox_id"`. So, the event is fired for `label` as well as for `checkbox`.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label for="test_0" class="">Fall</label>
        <input id="test_0" name="offering_cycle" type="checkbox" value="1" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="test_1" class="">Spring</label>
        <input id="test_1" name="offering_cycle" type="checkbox" value="2" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="test_2" class="">Summer</label>
        <input id="test_2" name="offering_cycle" type="checkbox" value="3" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="test_3" class="">Other</label>
        <input id="test_3" name="offering_cycle" type="checkbox" value="4" />
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Take the `input` out of `label`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/fdm1pmj2/5/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan That's what I was just thinking. Changing the markup is not an option. You think returning `false` like bitsm suggested is a good solution?

Comment: The solution is not to take the input out of label.

Comment: @jefffabiny actually you should use `event.preventDefault()` - see my answer for more details.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Let the OP decide

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan The question was `WHY`, and I think I've answered it

Answer (score 1):

To explain what happens:

- Input is clicked, but since the LABEL is bound to that Input using `for` attribute and for simply being it's child element, here's your first registered event.
- Than the input propagates the click (all elements propagate clicks) down to LABEL, and since the label is your delegated element - here's your second event being triggered.

Since you wrapped your Input Checkboxes inside a LABEL element,
you can actually **listen the even on the `input`**:

```
$('label[for*=test_] input').on('click',function(){
    $('div#target').append($(this).closest("label").clone());    
});
```

and than clone the parent label.  ***[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rq6y4sw6/)***

---

Another way to prevent that attributed connection between LABEL and the inner INPUT is to stop the input from propagating the event letting the bounding label's checkbox do its job: **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rq6y4sw6/3/)**

```
$("label:input").on("click", function( evt ) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
});
$('label[for*=test_]').on('click',function(){
    $('div#target').append($(this).clone());
});
```

---

Otherwise you *could* **prevent the default LABEL's behavior**   ***[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rq6y4sw6/2/)***
that triggers back events from the bound INPUT and that's using `e.preventDefault()` **but your (hidden) input checkbox will not get checked!**

```
$('label[for*=test_]').on('click',function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div#target').append($(this).clone()); 
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: For some reason I cannot get this to work. I'm trying to use your `stopPropagation()` example. I need to toggle the class instead of clone an element. I did the cloning for illustrative purposes. When I change the line to `toggleClass()` instead of `clone()` you can see the class is never added. http://jsfiddle.net/rq6y4sw6/4/

Comment: @jefffabiny that's cause the input and it's labelled text (labelled by LABEL) was the first to register the event, and since the event is in stop - the label cannot change class! Got it? :) If you've only taken in consideration my first example... here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rq6y4sw6/6/

Answer (score 0):

The *for* attribute on a given label should be linked to the *name* of the input not the *id*.

You can call the method `stopPropagation` on an event and you can inject the event into the click handler.

Example:

```
$('label[for*=test_]').on('click',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Example html:

```
<div class="parent something">
    <div class="child something">
    </div>
</div>
```

Now if you have a click handler on `div.something` it won't fire twice but you can still use both.

Sources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation
- https://learn.jquery.com/events/inside-event-handling-function/

Comment: This did not work when I made your changes in jsfiddle. The idea of stopping the propogation is correct, but this markup isn't working. http://jsfiddle.net/fdm1pmj2/18/

Comment: From the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-label-for) for the "for" attribute of the label element: "If the attribute is specified, the attribute's value must be the ID of a labelable element in the same Document as the label element." By giving the "for" attribute an invalid value, you've disassociated it with the input. That is why it gets only one click event in your fiddle. It no longer causes the input to get checked/unchecked though. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patv6p8y/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what I said in the comment. It generates two click events, do this instead and it works like a charm: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fdm1pmj2/2/)

```
$('input').on('click',function(){
   console.log("clicked");
    $('div#target').append($(this).parent().clone());    
});
```

You might want to rename your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Rather try this.

Add a common class to all Label's and fire event on that one.
Like this :

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label for="test_0" class="testClass">
            <input id="test_0" name="offering_cycle" type="checkbox" value="1"> Fall
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="test_1" class="testClass">
            <input id="test_1" name="offering_cycle" type="checkbox" value="2"> Spring
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="test_2" class="testClass">
            <input id="test_2" name="offering_cycle" type="checkbox" value="3"> Summer
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="test_3" class="testClass">
            <input id="test_3" name="offering_cycle" type="checkbox" value="4"> Other
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And than,

```
$(".testClass").on('click',function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('testing');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The click event is fired twice: once for the label, and once for the checkbox. You need to select only the checkbox.

```
$('label[for*=test_] > input').on('click',function(){
    $('div#target').append($(this).parent().clone());    
});
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/fdm1pmj2/17/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this...

```
$("label").find("*").click(function( event ) {
     event.stopPropagation();
});

$('label[for*=test_]').on('click',function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('test');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your Form is sent two times. To block the second submit (which also is a security issue) you can use this function on the Form. In my Example the form has the Class .comment-form but you can add any form class Name you want.

```
blockSecondSubmit('.comment-form');

function blockSecondSubmit($form) {
    $($form).on('submit', function () {
        $($form).on('submit', function () {
            return false;
        });
    });
}
```