# Angular 6 bootstrap multiselect item click firing twice

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4, angular6

I have below stackblitz

When I move click event form li to input change, it fired once, but

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

does not work.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-pvjfbv?file=index.html

Please help I spent alot of time, but could not manage to make it work

Comment: (change)="SelectElementCliked($event,item)" use change event instead of click event

Comment: I treid, that,but it does not worked,

Answer (score 1):

Removing the 'label' element surrounding the 'input' tag fixes the issue.

```
<div class="flx" style="align-items: flex-start">
    <div style="flex: 1;">       
        <div class="dropdown_23 drp-custom-select-container modal-select-custom">
            <div class="btn-group keepopen bootstrap-select form-control input-sm ddlcustomselect" data="Select">
                <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
                    <span #spnSelectedText class="filter-option pull-left" style="width: calc(100% - 20px);overflow: hidden;margin-right: 20px;">Select</span>&nbsp;
                    <span class="bs-caret">
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </span>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu open" role="combobox" style="max-height: 482px; overflow: hidden;">
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="listbox" aria-expanded="true" style="max-height: 470px; overflow-y: auto;">

                            <li *ngFor="let item of data_source" (click)="SelectElementCliked($event,item)" >                                
                                    <input type="checkbox"/>
                                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                    <span class="text">{{item.Text}}</span>                                
                            </li>                                             
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783660/why-are-two-click-events-registered-in-this-html-css-jquery)

Comment: This cannot be removed as it has UI dependency

Comment: The link I shared has solution on fixing it while keeping the label.. take a look

Comment: Yes, that I can handle with multiple way, but i want to know why is this behaving such

Comment: Answer to why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783660/why-are-two-click-events-registered-in-this-html-css-jquery

Comment: @StepUp, Thanks for giving time, but as I said, I cannot change the element as it has UI dependency that has been developed by other

Answer (score 0):

you have to emit @output

in template file - apply change event on input check box instead of li

```
 <li *ngFor="let item of data_source"  >
    <label class="checkboxcontainer checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox"  (change)="SelectElementCliked($event, item)"/>
           <span class="checkmark"></span>
           <span class="text">{{item.Text}}</span>
     </label>
</li>
```

In ts file

```
 SelectElementCliked(event: any, item: any) {

      if ( event.target.checked ) {
        console.log(item);
         this.onItemSelected.emit(item);
      }

    }
```

Comment: I missed that emiit while forking, i updated, but that not working, it firing twice

Answer (score 0):

changing the < li > content to as follows fixes the issue

```
<li *ngFor="let item of data_source" (click)="SelectElementCliked($event,item)" >
                            <label class="checkboxcontainer checkbox-inline">
                                <input [id]="item.Value" [name]="item.Value" type="checkbox"  />
                                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                <label  (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" [for]="item.Value" class="text">{{item.Text}}</label>
                            </label>
                        </li>
```

on clicking the label 2 events are propagated to the parent component , hence emiting 2 events. you may block the click of the label element using stopproagation

Comment: @Md. Parvez Alam : the 'why' is due to event bubbling