# Click Issue with input[type=radio] in label tag

Tags: jquery, html

When I perform JQuery click function `.click()` on `.option`, it returns result two times. I would like to show it only one time. Check console log for instance.

```js
$(".option").click(function() {
     console.log($(this).attr("class"));
    });
```

```css
.option {
height :20px;
background:gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="option">
  <label for="opt-1"><input type="radio" name="option-name" id="opt-1"> Walk the dog</label>
 </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no other element with class="option" in your html?

Comment: I don't find any same class either. It must be label attribute issue.

Comment: @jeprubio no. Check the code I pasted.

Comment: Oh, yes, I didn't see that it was a code snippet because I was on my smartphone and the run button is hidden in the mobile version.

Comment: I have solved this issue from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783660/why-are-two-click-events-registered-in-this-html-css-jquery